# how to replace text based on date in columns in vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a basic data which comprises 16000 rows and 40 columns. Among them i have to compare a column(A) that has dates with the date(Today's date plus 3months) and replace the text in the other column(B).

If the Today's date plus 3months is greater than column(A), it should be replace  `90 days` with `180 days`, where we have `180 days` in the column(B). I have attached a picture with two columns in it.

Problem: Its replacing the text only for few cells and also not deleting the rows that is less than the `Today's date plus 3months`.

Im taking the date from the userform. Here is code for the userform

userform code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function UserEnteredValue(Optional Prompt As String = "Please choose current date", Optional Default As String) As String
    With Me        
        .DTPicker1.Value = Date
        .DTPicker1.SetFocus        
        .Show
    End With
    With UserForm1
        If .Tag = "Ok" Then
            UserEnteredValue = .DTPicker1.Value
        End If
    End With
    Load UserForm1
End Function

Private Sub Cancel_Click()
Unload UserForm1.DTPicker1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click()
With Label1
   'to display text
    .caption.Text = "Date is for folder"
    'text alignment set to center
    .TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter
End With
End Sub

Private Sub Ok_Click()
    Me.Tag = "Ok"
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub userform_initialize()
Me.DTPicker1.Value = Date
End Sub
```

My code:

```
sub vba()

Dim wkb as workbook
Dim p as integer
Dim Fdate as string
Dim uiResult As String 

UserForm1.Show                      

 uiResult = UserForm1.DTPicker1.Value
 If uiResult = vbNullString Then
       MsgBox "canceled"
  Els
End If

Fdate = Format(DateAdd("m", 3, uiResult), "dd.mm.yyyy")

With wkb.Worksheets("abc").Cells(1, 1)

     For p = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row To 2 Step -1

      If Fdate > .Cells(p, "A").Value Then

.Cells(p, "B").Replace What:="(c)  <= 180 Days", Replacement:="(c)  <= 90 Days", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False

  Else
  If Future_date < .Cells(p, "A").Value Then
  .Rows(p).EntireRow.Delete

  End If
  End If
 Next p
 End With

end sub
```

The problem is. its not showing the exact results what i want. All i need the the macro must replace `90 days`  with  `180 days` if `Fdate` is greater than column(A) dates. if `Fdate` is less than must delete the entire row.

As i'm getting problem that , replacing the text for all the cell values where we have `180 days` and deleting only some columns.

[image]
[image]

Please someone help me out.
Note: In the picture you cannot find the `180 days` because its located somewhere in the 16000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think a part of your problem lies in this line: `Fdate = Format(DateAdd("m", 3, uiResult), "dd.mm.yyyy")`

The `Format` function returns a string value, not a date, so when you compare it the value in the cell, it is doing a string comparison. Strings compare based on stepping from left to right. As an example, the following test would result in false: `"01.01.2016" > 02.01.1999"` Clearly, year 2016 is greater than year 1999, but string don't recognize the year, and only recognize that 2 is greater than 1.

A quick workaround is to parse through the date fields in your loop, using code similar to the following:

```
Sub TestDate()
    Dim a As Variant
    Dim dDate As Date

    a = Split(ActiveCell, ".")
    dDate = DateSerial(a(2), a(1), a(0))

    MsgBox dDate

End Sub
```

Comment: the date format is working fine for me. If I use the date data type its not showing the exact date format .